# Datatables not filter sum amount on footer

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables to show some data on my admin panel.

but when I use the search option to filter results its not effecting on the footer sum amount and the amount remain as it is? any idea how to solve it?

```js
<?php if(isset($data_tables)) { ?>

    jQuery('#<?php echo $data_tables_name ?>').DataTable({
        "filter": "applied",     
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages

        if (api.column(2).data().length) {
            total_revenue = api
                .column( 2 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        } );
        } else {
            total_revenue = '';
        }

        $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
            total_revenue.toFixed(2)
        );

    },
    "lengthMenu": [ [12, 50, 100, -1], [12, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    responsive: true,

    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
     "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "<?php echo site_url(); ?>public/admin/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
     }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [selector-modifier](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) option for [column()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29) function to request filtered columns only by using `{ search:'applied' }`. By default, `column()` returns all data for all pages in the current order without filtering applied. Using `selector-modifier`, you can modify that behavior.

Total amount for rows which match the current search applied to the table on all pages:

```
if (api.column(2, { search:'applied' }).data().length) {
   total_revenue = api
      .column( 2, { search:'applied' } )
      .data()
      .reduce( function (a, b) {
         return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      });
} else {
   total_revenue = 0;
}
```

**Update**: `total_revenue` has to be assigned to `0` in order for code to work when there is no data in the table.

See the example below for demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages

        if (api.column(3, { search:'applied' }).data().length) {
            total_revenue = api
                .column( 3, { search:'applied' } )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        } );
        } else {
            total_revenue = 0;
        }

        $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
            total_revenue.toFixed(2)
        );

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `column(2)` you target the column for all rows, also those not visible. You need to use `column(2, {search:'applied'})` in order to work on only those columns made visible by the search / filter.

```js
if (api.column(2, {search:'applied'}).data().length>0) {
    total_revenue = api
       .column( 2, {search:'applied'} )
       .data()
       .reduce( function (a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
       });
} else {
    total_revenue = 0;
}
```

Have also corrected the `if` evaluation, and `total_revenue = ''` as in your code would cause errors.

your code working in a demo ->**http://jsfiddle.net/g28tu12e/**
dataTables selector modifiers -> https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier

Answer (score 0):

Here my Working codes 
https://jsfiddle.net/ua3tnz8b/1/

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function () {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
        return (a*1) + (b*1); 
         });
});

var table = $("table").DataTable();

$("table").on('search.dt', function() {

    var one = table.column( 0, {page:'current'} ).data().sum();
    var two = table.column( 1, {page:'current'} ).data().sum();


    one =  isNaN( one )? '&nbsp;' : one ;

    two =  isNaN( one )? '&nbsp;' : two ;

        var data = "<tr>"+
               "<th>Total: "+one+"</th>"+
               "<th>Total :"+two+"</th>"+
               "<th>&nbsp;</th>"+
               "<th>&nbsp;</th>"+
               "<th>&nbsp;</th>"+
               "<th>&nbsp;</th>"+
               "</tr>";

               $("#tfoot").html(data);
               });
</script>
```